# Programmatically creating VS solution/project files

Tags: c, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a C project with a very nice rake build system in place. Unit test runners, mocks, as well as some boilerplate code, are generated.

The requirement is for the pc based stuff to be available in VS. I know the VS .sln and .proj formats are undocumented. 
I also know that cmake can generate VS solution files as long as it's own files are up-to-date so my fallback solution is to create the cmake file structure/lists and use it to create the VS solutions.

Since my fallback reeks of duplication, I am looking for pointers to any other tools, templates or documentation that would allow me to create VS project and solution files.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 6):

Actually, .vcproj file format is documented and you can find it on the MSDN website:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2(v=VS.100).aspx

And here is the Solution file documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951(VS.80).aspx

I'm sure you can find more useful information on MSDN.